# PHP PEAR отсутствует файл common.php

Tags: php

```
Warning: require_once(HTML/Common.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\php\pear\Table.php on line 68

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'HTML/Common.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\php\pear\Table.php on line 68
```

В файле Table.php есть строка

```
require_once 'HTML/Common.php';
```

Файла "Common.php" в папке pear не существует, где его взять?

Comment: а где PEAR брали? и целиком ли вы его взяли.

Comment: [PEAR Common2 ?](https://pear.php.net/packages.php?catpid=10)

Comment: @teran установил XAMPP, PEAR был в комплекте

Comment: если используете [HTML_Table](https://pear.php.net/package/HTML_Table) то там внизу страницы в зависимостях указано [HTML Common](https://pear.php.net/package/HTML_Common/)

Comment: @teran скачал HTML_Common 1.2.5 и забросил файл туда, где он не может найти, это вроде проходит, но тут же не может найти
Failed opening required 'HTML/Table/Storage.php'

среди списка что давали выше, Storage нету

Comment: сам не пользую, чем смог - помог (: все нужное по-любому можно найти на сайте PEAR.в `Common` то его точно не будет, ибо ищет в папке `Table`. Поищите его вообще в вашем каталоге `php\pear`, может понадобится только исправить `include_path`.